# Did Hans Landa recognize Shosanna?

Tags: inglourious-basterds

In the movie Inglorious Basterds, the scene where Hans Landa and Shosanna were in the restaurant, Hans Landa says "I did have something else I wanted to ask you, but right now, for the life of me, I can't remember what it is."

When he was just staring at her, did he recognized her and was just playing, or was it just something he tried to remember but couldn't?